# Duda angular, formularios y contadores ciclo for

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

Tengoqu hacer un quiz donde hay alrededor de 40 preguntas, en estas cada pregunta tiene 3 opciones. 
Lo que quiero hacer es que desde angular contar cuantas veces eligió cada una de esas 3 opciones y guardarlo a mi base de datos. que esta todo en el backend con nodejs. (las opciones las pongo en un select, quizas sea mejor de otra forma).

Espero me puedan ayudar, e buscado información pero por mi cuenta no e podido entender como hacerlo.

Alguien me pueda explicar desde un mini código, como podría funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

No se que version de angular estas usando, si te entiendo bien tienes un select y deseas saber cuantas veces cambia el usuario de respuesta antes de enviar.

- imagino que tienes algun valor desde el select (id, un string...)

  opcion1
  ...

  1) usa un evento de cambio, leer los cambios en el select con angular 4 seria algo como esto: (ngModelChange)="ejemplo($event)" agregalo al select.

2) desde tu archivo .js o .ts usa el metodo "ejemplo" que le agregaste a el select para capturar el valor del select y así puedes contar cuantas veces cambia el valor.